# django image can not be seen

Tags: django, django-templates

I followed the steps indicated in the tutorials but the image is still not seen. It finds it but it does not show it: "GET /static/imagenes/triste.png HTTP / 1.1" 404 1782. The images are in static/imagenes.

```
{% load static %}
<img src= "{% static 'imagenes/feliz.png' %}" alt="hola" >
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('configuracionSecreta/', include('apps.configuracion.urls')),
    path('dialogo/', include('apps.dialogo.urls')),
    path('posicionamiento/', include('apps.dialogo_pos.urls')),
    path('resultados/', include('apps.resultados_test.urls')),
    path('', include('apps.test_datos.urls')),

]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)


├───.vscode
├───apps
│   ├───configuracion
│   ├───dialogo
│   ├───dialogo_pos
│   ├───resultados_test
│   └───test_datos
├───media
├───static
│   ├───bower_components
│   ├───imagenes
├───templates
│   ├───base
│   ├───configuracion
│   ├───dialogo
│   ├───dialogo_pos
│   ├───resultados_test
│   └───test_datos
└───tfg_project

#dialogo_pos/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from apps.dialogo_pos.views import *
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
    path('', dialogoPosIni.as_view(), name='inicio'),
    path('final', dialogoPosFin.as_view(), name='fin')
] 
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Have you initialized `urlpatterns` before `+=`? Where is your file located on drive? Is DEBUG=True or False? And remove STATIC_ROOT folder from STATICFILES_DIR.

Comment: post your complete `urls.py` here where you are adding static routes.

Comment: show your image model and urls

Comment: I have DEBUG in true. I have urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('configuracionSecreta/', include('apps.configuracion.urls')),
    path('dialogo/', include('apps.dialogo.urls')),
    path('posicionamiento/', include('apps.dialogo_pos.urls')),
    path('resultados/', include('apps.resultados_test.urls')),
    path('', include('apps.test_datos.urls')),

] defined.

Comment: In models i dont use the images.

Comment: Please show `apps.test_datos.urls` urlpatterns and your folder structure. Once again, where is any of mentioned files located on drive?